# CSS flex overflow-y firefox bug

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox, overflow

I'm trying to make 2 vertical flex containers fill the screen and both be scrollable. I can get it to work properly in chrome but firefox is failing. when the content is dynamically inserted it's container expands to fit the content instead of staying flexed and showing scroll-bars. to see the issue open this jsfiddle in chrome vs firefox and click the `fill top` button.

https://jsfiddle.net/np6jgs45/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script>
    function fillit() {
        document.getElementById('tophalf').innerHTML = "shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>";
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <div style="height: 100vh; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
      <div style="padding: 20px; background-color: gray;">header</div>

      <div style="flex: 1; display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
        <nav style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 198); width: 200px;">
          menu<br />
          <button onClick="fillit()">fill top</button>
        </nav>
        <div style="flex: 1; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
          <div
            style="
              flex: 1;
              display: flex;
              background: repeating-linear-gradient(
                45deg,
                #f7f7f7,
                #f7f7f7 10px,
                #f1f1f1 10px,
                #f1f1f1 20px
              );
              align-items: center;
              flex-direction: column;
            "
          >
            <div
              style="
                flex: 1;
                width: 600px;
                display: flex;
                position: relative;
                max-width: 100%;
                flex-direction: column;
                height: 0px;
              "
            >
              <div
                id="tophalf"  
                style="
                  flex: 1;
                  overflow-y: auto;
                  background-color: rgba(250, 158, 158, 0.521);
                "
              ></div>
              <div
                style="
                  flex: 1;
                  overflow-y: auto;
                  background-color: rgba(144, 243, 144, 0.555);
                "
              ></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share your code here so we don't have to go off site

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do is add `height: 50%;` to both the tophalf and bottom half divs,  And then change the containing div's height from 0 to `max-height: 90vh;` and it should make it work in firefox.

Here's the fiddle if you want to play around with it: https://jsfiddle.net/9h7z4udy/

See here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script>
    function fillit() {
        document.getElementById('tophalf').innerHTML = "shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>shus<br/>";
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <div style="height: 100vh; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
      <div style="padding: 20px; background-color: gray;">header</div>

      <div style="flex: 1; display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
        <nav style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 198); width: 200px;">
          menu<br />
          <button onClick="fillit()">fill top</button>
        </nav>
        <div style="flex: 1; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
          <div
            style="
              flex: 1;
              display: flex;
              background: repeating-linear-gradient(
                45deg,
                #f7f7f7,
                #f7f7f7 10px,
                #f1f1f1 10px,
                #f1f1f1 20px
              );
              align-items: center;
              flex-direction: column;
            "
          >
            <div
              style="
                flex: 1;
                width: 600px;
                display: flex;
                position: relative;
                max-width: 100%;
                flex-direction: column;
                max-height: 90vh;
              "
            >
              <div
                id="tophalf"  
                style="
                  flex: 1;
                  height: 50%;
                  overflow-y: auto;
                  background-color: rgba(250, 158, 158, 0.521);
                "
              ></div>
              <div
                style="
                  flex: 1;
                    height: 50%;
                  
                  overflow-y: auto;
                  background-color: rgba(144, 243, 144, 0.555);
                "
              ></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't want to use absolute heights. my header height is actually dynamic. flex is supposed to be flexible. that's the whole point.